# Format number by selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to format a number by using a selector, both jQuery of JavaScript are fine.

I have a dynamic number that comes back from the API, but that comes back with many decimal place (i.e 3.5847549875398). I want to format it to 2 decimal places (i.e 3.58). Rounding is not necessary, but if there is an example with rounding that would be great!

Here is what I have, but it fails to round:

JSP:

```
<span class="floatRight distanceNum">
    <@= storeInfo.distance @> miles
</span>
```

JavaScript/jQuery (Within the onLoad function)

```
$(".distanceNum").toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Why not format it on the server?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/so57skyr/1/

Comment: You might need this `onLoad` `$(".distanceNum").text($(".distanceNum").text().toFixed(2));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your value from api to float then you should be able to achieve what you want. toFixed function will round your value also.

Here is the working code for you.

```
$(".distanceNum").text(parseFloat($(".distanceNum").text()).toFixed(2));
```

Let me know if it worked for you.

Happy Coding.